# Uncaught Error: Elementor How can i resolve this issue?

Tags: php

I am receiving this error after troubleshooting the elementor error

> Uncaught Error: Class ‘ElementorPro\Modules\ThemeBuilder\Module’ not found in /home/rangoliuser/public_html/wp-content/plugins/essential-addons-for-elementor-lite/includes/Classes/Asset_Builder.php:195
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /home/rangoliuser/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): Essential_Addons_Elementor\Classes\Asset_Builder->load_asset_per_location(Object(LaStudioKitThemeBuilder\Modules\ThemeBuilder\Classes\Locations_Manager))
> #1 /home/rangoliuser/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
> #2 /home/rangoliuser/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
> #3 /home/rangoliuser/public_html/wp-content/plugins/lastudio-element-kit/includes/modules/theme-builder/classes/locations-manager.php(54): do_action(‘elementor/theme…’, Object(LaStudioKitThemeBuilder\Modules\ThemeBuilder\Classes\Locations_Manager))
> #4 /home/rangoliuser/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): LaStudioKitThemeBuilder\Modules\ThemeBuilder\Classes\Locations_Manager->r

I am finding this error when i’m troubleshooting the error showing while opening elementor page editor.

The page I need help with: https://rangolicollections.in/

Comment: The "essential-addons-for-elementor-lite" plugin appears to be using a class from the main Elementor plugin that doesn't exist. This suggests a version mismatch. Elementor may have been updated and the addons plugin does not support the new version, or perhaps Elementor Pro is out of date and the addons plugin expects a newer version. Either way you'll need to contact the author of the addons plugin for further assistance.